# I've got problem with fine tuning of regex

Tags: regex, c#-2.0

i've got regex which was alright, but as it camed out doesn't work well in some situations

**Keep eye on message preview cause message editor do some tricky things with "\"**

> [\[]?[\^%#\$\*@\-;].*?[\^%#\$\*@\-;][\]]

its task is to find pattern which in general looks like that

> [ABA]

- A - char from set ^,%,#,$,*,@,-,;
- B - some text
- [ and ] are included in pattern

is expected to find all occurences of this pattern in test string

> Black fox [#sample1#] [%sample2%] - [#sample3#] eats blocks.

but instead of expected list of matches

- "[#sample1#]"
- "[%sample2%]"
- "[#sample3#]"

I get this

- "[#sample1#]"
- "[%sample2%]"
- "- [#sample3#]"

And it seems that this problem will occur also with other chars in set "A". So could somebody suggest changes to my regex to make it work as i need?

and less important thing, how to make my regex to exclude patterns which look like that

> [ABC]

- A - char from set ^,%,#,$,*,@,-,;
- B - some text
- C - char from set ^,%,#,$,*,@,-,; **other than A**
- [ and ] are included in pattern

for example

> [$sample1#] [%sample2@] [%sample3;]

thanks in advance

MTH

Comment: I just added the regex do detect ABA and ABC: could you confirm they work for you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\[([%#$*@;^-]).+?\1\]
```

applied to text:

```
Black fox [#sample1#] [%sample2%] - [#sample3#] [%sample4;] eats blocks.
```

matches

- `[#sample1#]`
- `[%sample2%]`
- `[#sample3#]`
- *but not* `[%sample4;]`

EDIT

This works for me (Output as expected, regex accepted by C# as expected):

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"\[([%#$*@;^-]).+?\1\]");
string s = "Black fox [#sample1#] [%sample2%] - [#sample3#] [%sample4;] eats blocks.";

MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(s);
foreach (Match m in mc)
{
  Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Comment: Yes but how would you detect ABC without using lookahead ? [^\1] does not work...

Comment: well c# RegEx engine seems not to like this expression, prhaps something was wrongly interpreted by message editor on this page?

Comment: Well, reading it again - *Not* matching ABC is a requirement. My regex matches ABA exclusively. No lookahead needed.

Comment: Ofcourse you're right, in testing app i've had "ExplicitCapture" on for regex. So numbers of groups was just not right, diagnostic message didn't gaved me clue, so i reviewed my code and changed it, Now all works  just fine, Thanks for your help

Comment: So is that what you've been after or is it just one more way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Why the first "?" in "[[]?"

```
\[[\^%#\$\*@\-;].*?[\^%#\$\*@\-;]\]
```

would detect your different strings just fine

To be more precise:

```
\[([\^%#\$\*@\-;])([^\]]*?)(?=\1)([\^%#\$\*@\-;])\]
```

would detect [ABA]

```
\[([\^%#\$\*@\-;])([^\]]*?)(?!\1)([\^%#\$\*@\-;])\]
```

would detect [ABC]

Comment: well it seems that i was making so much changes that i missed this

Answer (score 1):

You have an optional matching of the opening square bracket:

[\]]?

For the second part of you question (and to perhaps simplify) try this:

\[\%[^\%]+\%\]|\[\#[^\#]+\#\]|\[\$[^\$]+\$\]

In this case there is a sub pattern for each possible delimiter. The | character is "OR", so it will match if any of the 3 sub expressions match.

Each subexpression will:

- Opening bracket
- Special Char
- Everything that is not a special char (1)
- Special char
- Closing backet

(1) may need to add extra exclusions like ']' or '[' so it doesn't accidently match across a large body of text like:

[%MyVar#] blah blah [$OtherVar%]

Rob